# how to use `or` in css selector to select its child?

Tags: css

I want to select a child dom with below css selector:

```
.parentA .child{

}

.parentB .child{

}
```

how can I combine them into one selector? I have tried below but doesn't work:

```
.parentA,.parentB .child{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, there is no `OR` in CSS. There is only `AND` and you use `,` (comma) for it.

Which is to say whenever you want to assign the same set of rules to more than one selector, you can separate each case using a comma:

```
.parentA .child,
.parentB .child {
  /* rules here */
}
```

They apply separately, which is to say the above is equivalent with this non DRY (hence wrong) way of writing it:

```
.parentA .child {
  /* rules here */
}
.parentB .child {
  /* rules here */
}
```

To apply the DRY principle to selectors, if they share a pattern, you could use SASS (or other pre-processors) and nest selectors, like this:

```
.parentA, .parentB {
   .child {
     /* rules here */
   }
}
```

But SASS is a CSS pre-processor which, when parsed, will result in the CSS mentioned initially.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?:

```
.parentA > .child, 
.parentB > .child{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain CSS you have to repeat the entire selector, `.parentA .child, .parentB .child`, but if you use LESS, Sass or other preprocessors, you can do:

```
.parentA, .parentB {
    .child {
         color: red;
    }
}
```

Which will get compiled out to the former for you so you don't have to repeat yourself.